# Is there sufficient distinction between "gas" and "gas pains" to merit separate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a question tagged with both [gas](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas) and [gas-pain](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas-pain).

Should both tags remain, or should we make them synonyms?

Which should be the primary tag, if we keep one of them?

Do we need *either* of the tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I vote for one primary [gas](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas) tag, with [gas-pains](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas-pains) as a synonym.  For parenting purposes, it doesn't much matter if the gas actually hurts or not.  It's troublesome just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Karl's proposal is what I would have said too. As for the last part:

**Yes we need the tags,** simply because somebody entered them. It makes sense to distill them into a single tag (possibly with many synonyms) but if anybody finds any given tag useful, I don't want to remove it. Besides, it would be futile - without any synonyms to route it elsewhere, the next user can create the tag(s) again.